# Select All Sections and mark ones with user privileges by user id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have list of sections stored in database in table `Sections` with columns (`sectionId, sectionTypeId, sectionName`) and privileges in table `UserPrivilages` with columns (`userPrivilagesId, userId, sectionTypeId`).

I want to select all sections from table `Sections` but mark those `sectionTypes` by `sectionTypeId` stored in `UserPrivilages` by `userId`.

Something like:

```
SELECT sectionId, sectionTypeId, sectionName, (true/false) as privilage
FROM Sections
```

If I JOIN this with table `UserPrivilages` I get results only exist in both tables, but I want to have also Sections that user don`t have`privilages` for.

This true/false is from `UserPrivilages` table if `sectionTypeId` from `Sections` table exists in `UserPrivilages` table by `userId` than return true, else false

So result would be for example

```
SectionId   sectionTypeId   sectionName   privilage
1           1               Name1         true or 1
2           2               Name2         false or 0
```

Comment: It's **privilege** - not privilage ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a left join, and possibly a `COALESCE` to substitute an answer when no row exists in privilages:

```
SELECT
  s.sectionId,
  s.sectionTypeId,
  s.sectionName,
  COALESCE(p.privilage,0) as privilage
FROM
  Sections s
    left join
  Privilages p
    on
       s.sectionTypeId = p.sectionTypeId and
       p.UserId = @User
```

Which will have a `0` wherever no match exists.

---

Or, possibly, re-reading the question, you're not selecting a column from `p`, you just want to check for existence:

```
SELECT
  s.sectionId,
  s.sectionTypeId,
  s.sectionName,
  CASE WHEN p.userPrivilagesId is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as privilage
FROM
  Sections s
    left join
  Privilages p
    on
       s.sectionTypeId = p.sectionTypeId and
       p.UserId = @User
```

(Assuming `userPrivilagesId` is a non-NULL column in `p`).

Comment: Yes this works for me, the only problem for now is that I don`t have stored this privilage in UserPrivilages table it will not return true/false I can chane this p.privilage with p.userPrivilagesId and get the right results but it wont return true/false but id/false. How can I manage that without having this true/false prviilage in UserPrivilages table.

Comment: @janilemy - I updated my answer with a second query - have you seen that one also? It only returns 0 or 1, based on a row existing or not in the `privilages` table (also, it's usually spelled privilege)

Comment: O.k this second solution is better for me. Thanks for your help